# How to define action on button that is generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am getting the data retrieved from the database and displaying it in a  tag, I am trying to capture the primary key from the database as the value of the button using java script. How do i do this ?

I have tried this using the javascript with in while loop and outside while loop and failed.   `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {}`

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {
?>
<div class="col-lg-4 ">
    <div class="card" style="width:22rem;">
    <div class="card-body" >
        <!--  <div class="card" style="width: 25rem;height: 30rem;background-color:OFFWHITE ;">
           <p class="card-text" >--> <label>Customer Name:</label>
                <?php echo $row['Name'];?><br>
                    <label>Phone Number:</label>
                <?php echo $row['phoneno'];?><br>
                    <?php $ticketid = $records['ticketid']; ?>
            <form method="post">
                <select class="form-control" name="status">
                <option value="Open" selected>Open</option>
                <option value="Pending">Accept</option>
                <option value="Reject">Reject</option>
                </select>
                <button id="ticket" value="<?php echo $row['ticketid'];?>" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn">Submit</button>       
            </form> 
        <!-- </p> -->
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<script>
                function myFunction(){
                var ticketid =  "<?php echo $records['ticketid'];?>";
                var x = document.getElementById("ticket").value;
                alert(x);

                //alert(ticketid);
                //echo $status;
                }
</script>
```

I want to capture the primary key of each data displayed on the div, which is in card view. How do i do it?

Comment: just do:- `onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $row['ticketid'];?>)"` and use this id in your function. it's simple

Comment: You can set the primary key as the `id` of your button, and then use `event.target.id` in your `myFunction`.

Comment: <script>
                function myFunction(){
                var ticketid =  "<?php echo $row['ticketid'];?>";
                var x = document.getElementById("ticket").value;
                alert(x);
                }
            </script>

Tried using this, but this returns the same primary key every time a onclick() event occurs.

Comment: Try changing your while loop to a foreach

Comment: can you share a link related to foreach @GarthBaker

Comment: I added an answer for you

Comment: you miss to show us the relevant code (the js) where you want to use that ID. The PHP part looks fine (unless you are trying to echo a value that you don't select. But either in that case you don't show the query...